# C# compiler doesn't complain when not all code paths return

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, using

I had a function that was returning in a `using` block:

```
int f() {
  using (...) {
     ...
     return someVar;
  }
}
```

I just noticed this and moved the `return` outside of the `using` block to the outermost function scope, because I felt that that's where the `return` should be.

But I'm confused why the compiler wasn't complaining that not all code paths were returning. Is it simply because if it failed to initialize a resource, we would get a crash, so it doesn't matter?

Take this example:

```
class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    f();
  }

  public static int f() {
    using(A a = new A()) {
      return 1;
    }
  }
}

class A : IDisposable{
  public void Dispose() { }
}
```

The compiler doesn't care that we only return in `using`. However, I thought `using` statements were basically syntactic sugar for `try/catch`

If we replace

```
using(A a = new A()) {
  return 1;
}
```

with

```
A a = new A();;
try  {
  return 1;
}

catch (Exception e) { }
finally {
  if (a != null) {
    ((IDisposable) a).Dispose();
  }
}
```

Indeed the compiler complains:

> error CS0161: `MainClass.f()': not all code paths return a value

Why doesn't it complain in the other case?

Is it simply what I said above? **If it fails to initialize a resource, we would get a crash, so the compiler decides it doesn't matter.**

Comment: It's just a `try-finally`, there is no `catch`.  If you remove the `catch` in your code you will not get the compilation error.

Comment: Why would you want to pull the `return` out of the `using`?  It needlessly makes the code much more complex and harder to read, while adding nothing in return.

Comment: @Servy I don't understand how it makes it "much more complex". The reason is that I want to return in the outermost block - it somehow feels more correct.

Comment: @pushkin: but you could define local variables in the `using` block you cannot longer access outside. Basically `using` is meant to make code more readable (it will dispose the constructed object, regardless where you return).

Comment: @pushkin It means you now need to change the scope of your variables to also be outside of the `using`, even though conceptually they never make sense outside of that context.  And conceptually you still have the same situation as returning from inside the `using`, in that you now need to prove that the variable is definitely assigned when the `using` runs, which is an identical problem to proving that the `using` having a return makes the endpoint of the method unreachable.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, @Servy good point! In my case, the variable I was returning was outside of the `using` block, though now that you mention it, maybe it shouldn't be.

Comment: Can you describe why you believed that `using` imposes a `catch`?  I am interested to learn how people come to believe false things about programming languages.

Comment: @EricLippert When I researched this peculiarity (I'm new to C#), I stumbled upon references to `try/finally`, but I must not have read carefully enough. I saw `try/finally`, but was so unused to seeing `try` without `catch`, that I must have convinced myself that I actually saw `try/catch`. I did see examples that used `try/finally` instead of `using`, but as I have never used `try/finally` statements (without `catch`), I blindly expected that if `try/catch/finally` causes a compilation error, so would `try/finally`.

Comment: @pushkin: Thanks! Understanding how people overgeneralize, etc, is helpful when designing new language features.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually the:

```
using(var objectName = <init-expression>) {
    //...
}
```

Is more or less equivalent to:

```
objectName = <init-expression>;
try {
    //...
} finally {
    objectName.Dispose();
}
```

So it is a `try`-`finally`-block: if something goes wrong during the execution, the exception will be thrown out of the method (mostly after the `finally` part is done).

A `try`-`finally` however does not create an alternative code path: if the `try`-part returns something or throws an error, it will first execute the `finally`-part, but then either throw the exception or return what is ought to be returned.

Answer (score 4):

Essentially, yes. The `using` statement will throw it's exception up the stack. Catching the exception and using a finally block that doesn't return means that the method both doesn't throw an exception and doesn't return.

The compiler also doesn't complain about methods like the following

```
public int SuperCool(){
   throw new NotImplementedException("bummer");
}
```

To expand a little since I missed an edit with the catch block not being there originally:

Having the `catch` block "eats" the exception causing it to not move further up the stack and the compiler to notice that there is no path that returns a value or an exception.